# Pull specific contact, if not available then next highest level

Tags: sql, ms-access, criteria

I previously asked how to pull only the highest level contact in MS Access and the answer I received (a simple Min SQL statement) worked perfectly. This time I need to pull a specific contact, if that contact isn't available, it needs to be the next highest level.

In our database we have accounts that are a Company and within the Company account there are 1-4 contacts. These contacts are listed as A,B,C, & D. I have a query that pulls the company and lists all the contacts associated with it.

The Company is grouped by "OrganizationID". 
The contact field is listed as "Position".

**My question is... is there a way to just pull only the "C" contact, then if no C, then B, if no B & C, then A, if no A,B, or C, then D?**

Comment: Try the [NZ function](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Nz-Function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c).

Comment: I think you are best off with a recordset.

Comment: `SELECT Top 1 Contact, Switch (Position="C", 1, Position="B", 2, Position="A",3, Position-"D",4) As UsePosition FROM Company ORDER BY 2` -- or similar

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I couldn't get the NZ function to work, or the Switch.  I ended up making a small table with the positions and adding a Position2 field with a number value. I then used the Min SQL statement I used previously based on the Position2 field. It worked!